# How to show multiple y-axis in plotly express

Tags: plotly

I'm working on a problem in which I need to plots columns of a dataframe in which all columns have different ranges. A similar dataset is tips from plotly.

Once I add `fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)` to my code I can clearly see that x-axes are updated and shown as expected but when I add `fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)`, I see that my plot is updated but I can see only one axis (the far left one).

So, my question is how to show all y-axes in this plot:

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.tips()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="total_bill", y="tip", color='sex', facet_col="day")
fig.update_xaxes(matches=None)
fig.update_yaxes(matches=None)
fig.show()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make faceted plots in Plotly have their own individual YAxes tick labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60997189/how-can-i-make-faceted-plots-in-plotly-have-their-own-individual-yaxes-tick-labe)

Comment: Hi Ali, you need to explicitly modify `showticklabels`. This is explained on the answer above.