# How to show axis labels of all subplots when the labels are strings?

Tags: python, plotly, facet, plotly-express

#### Problem summary

Whenever I try to create a plot with [plotly express 5.18.0](https://plotly.com/python/plotly-express/) containing a subplot *and* axes labels that are not numbers, I only get labels for the first subplot subsequent subplots show empty axis labels.

How can I ensure that all subplots show their respective axes labels, even if they contain strings?

#### Example data

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

N = 100
food = ["Dim sum", "Noodles", "Burger", "Pizza", "Pancake"]
drink = ["Beer", "Wine", "Soda", "Water", "Fruit juice", "Coffee", "Tea"]
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "age": np.random.randint(8, 99, N),
        "favourite_food": np.random.choice(food, N, replace=True),
        "favourite_drink": np.random.choice(drink, N, replace=True),
        "max_running_speed": np.random.random(N)*20,
        "number_of_bicycles": np.random.randint(0, 5, N)
    }
)
df.age.replace({range(0, 19): "Kid", range(19, 100): "Adult"}, inplace=True)
```

Random 5 rows:

|  | age | favourite_food | favourite_drink | max_running_speed | number_of_bicycles |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Adult | Dim sum | Wine | 8.57536 | 2 |
| 65 | Kid | Pizza | Water | 9.45698 | 1 |
| 57 | Kid | Pancake | Beer | 11.1445 | 0 |
| 84 | Adult | Dim sum | Soda | 8.80699 | 0 |
| 45 | Adult | Pizza | Fruit juice | 17.7258 | 4 |

#### Demonstration of problem

If I now create a figure with two subplots:

- First subplot contains the distribution of the max. running speed (a number)
- Second subplot contains the distribution of the number of bicycles (a number)

For convenience I use the `facet_col` argument in combination with the [wide-form support of plotly express](https://plotly.com/python/wide-form/) and the formatting updates I found in this [related Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60997189/1256347)):

```py
px.histogram(
    df,
    x=["max_running_speed", "number_of_bicycles"],
    facet_col="variable",
    color="age",
    barmode="group",
    histnorm="percent",
    text_auto=".2r",
).update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True).update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)
```

[image]

All works as it should ✅: I get separate ranges x- and y-axes and I get separate labels on the x-axes.

Now I do the same, but for the columns with text data:

```py
px.histogram(
    df,
    x=["favourite_food", "favourite_drink"],
    facet_col="variable",
    color="age",
    barmode="group",
    histnorm="percent",
    text_auto=".2r",
).update_xaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True).update_yaxes(matches=None, showticklabels=True)
```

[image]

Now there's a problem ❌: The x-axis of the right plot does not show the names of the favourite drinks.

#### What I've tried

I checked the underlying data JSON object, as I noticed that when I hover over the bars of the right plot, the "value" field is empty:

[image]

But when I inspect the JSON object in the `.data` key of the figure, I see that x-values are present for both histograms:

[image]

Comment: It seems you found a bug, which I think happens in Plotly.js and is caused by having non-shared+categorical axes (if you remove the `matches=None` on xaxes, you get the labels back but all of them appears on both subplots)... The best you can do for now is to reproduce the bug directly with Plotly.js and [open an issue](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues) with all the details (maybe you can start with a smaller dataset and use `fig.to_json(pretty=True)` then get rid of layout templates and other non-essential stuff).

Comment: I've opened an issue: https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/6806

Comment: Sorry the issue might rather be in px.express (ie. in plotly.py rather than plotly.js) since you managed to get labels working using `go.Histogram()`. It appears `px.histogram()` with `facet_col` explicitly set the same bingroup 'x' to every trace, while the default (implicit, working) behavior is only the traces that are on the same subplot belong to the same bingroup. So you can fix the issue by adding `fig.update_traces(bingroup='x2', row=1, col=2)` to your original code, and maybe move the issue to https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the plotly contributors [suggested](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/4452#issuecomment-1843884337) I use the `.update_traces(bingroup=None)` on my figure. This indeed shows the missing categories on the right plot and is a viable workaround for now.